# How to set Python scipy's nquad options to integrate near a singularity (avoid divide by zero)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, arguments, divide-by-zero

I'm trying to use Python's scipy library to integrate a certain function, which involves dividing by zero when `c = +1`. Therefore, I want to integrate up to `c = 0.99`, but I cannot figure out how to set the various options and parameters, such that the integration works.

Here's a minimal example:

```
from scipy.integrate import nquad

options={'limit':5000,'epsrel':0.5e0}

results = []

for d in range(-4,5):
    f = lambda a,b,c: a**2*b**2 / (a**2 - 2*a*b*c + b**2 + d)
    temp = nquad( f, [[0,30],[0,30],[-1,0.99]], opts=[options,options,options] )
    results.append( [d, 4*10**(-8) * temp[0]] )

print(results)
```

I've tried to increase the limit, but this does not seem to help. I've also played around with the `epsrel` value, to no avail.

For what it's worth, I managed to do this quite easily in Mathematica, so I do know that it's possible. I assume it's just a matter of how I choose `nquad`'s options. For reference, this is Mathematica's output:

[image: Screenshot of Mathematica code]

There's probably a lot happening behind the scenes in `NIntegrate`, but still, the evaluation gets done in a few seconds without any trouble.

Comment: Using `for d in np.arange(-4, 5)` instead of `range(-4, 5)` will fix the `ZeroDivisionError`, that's not for `c=0` but for the denominator == 0.

Comment: Try with `options={'limit':50, 'epsrel':.5}`

Comment: You can see here https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/tebqhnrj that the singularity can happen into your defined range -4<=d<=4 for various values of a, b, c and always where d<=0

Comment: Why would you decrease the limit parameter, instead of increasing it? (I think 50 might be the standard value, but I could be wrong)

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why, but using a low subintervals limit (such as the default 50) you get the right results, similar to those you got in Mathematica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is an equilateral hyperbola of type

[image]

the singularity in your case is the vertical asymptote that happens for

[image]

so, to avoid the singularity, you can define your `f` as

```
f = lambda a,b,c: (a**2 * b**2) / (a**2 - 2*a*b*c + b**2 + d) \
                  if d != -(a**2 - 2*a*b*c + b**2) else 0
```

so we got

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import nquad

options={'limit':5000, 'epsrel':0.5e0}

results = []

for i, d in enumerate(np.arange(-4, 5)):
    f = lambda a,b,c: (a**2 * b**2) / (a**2 - 2*a*b*c + b**2 + d) \
                      if d != -(a**2 - 2*a*b*c + b**2) else 0
    temp = nquad( f, 
                 ranges=((0, 30), (0, 30), (-1, .99)),
                 opts=[options,options,options],
                )
    results.append( [d, 4*10**(-8) * temp[0]] )

res_arr = np.array(results)
print(res_arr)
```

that gives (you may get some warnings) almost the same results of Mathematica

```
[[-4.          0.01405795]
 [-3.          0.01393407]
 [-2.          0.01370157]
 [-1.          0.01351541]
 [ 0.          0.01335587]
 [ 1.          0.01321535]
 [ 2.          0.01308802]
 [ 3.          0.01297009]
 [ 4.          0.01285942]]
```

and plotting

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(res_arr[:,0], res_arr[:,1], 'k.')
plt.axvline(0, color='r', ls='--', lw=1)
```

[image]

Comment: That looks very intriguing, thank you! Just to be sure, the backslash in your definition of `f` is just used to start a new line, right?

Comment: YVW. Yes the backslash is for new line, to make it neater.